# Unable to simulate click on Menu Antd with jest and enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, antd

I'm trying to simulate ‍`click` on the Menu component. `Antd v4.3.1`

Component:

```js
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Menu } from 'antd'

import { SMALL_ICONS, PATHS } from '../../constants'

export const LeftMenu = ({ currentRoute, onMenuClick }) => {
  return (
    <Menu
      mode='inline'
      selectedKeys={[currentRoute]}
      onClick={onMenuClick}
      data-test='component-left-menu'
    >
      {Object.keys(PATHS).map((key, index) => (
        <Menu.Item
          key={key}
          icon={SMALL_ICONS[key]}
          data-test={`left-menu-item-${key}`}
        >
          {PATHS[key]}
        </Menu.Item>
      ))}
    </Menu>
  )
}

LeftMenu.propTypes = {
  currentRoute: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onMenuClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}
```

Test:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'

import { LeftMenu } from '../LeftMenu'

const onMenuClickMock = jest.fn()

const defaultProps = {
  currentRoute: '',
  onMenuClick: onMenuClickMock,
}

const setup = props => {
  const setupProps = { ...defaultProps, ...props }
  return shallow(<LeftMenu {...setupProps} />)
}

describe('click on first menu item', () => {
  const wrapper = setup()
  wrapper.simulate('click', { key: 'home' })
  expect(onMenuClickMock.mock.calls.count).toBe(1)
})
```

Result:

```
Expected: 1
Received: undefined
```

How should I simulate click on Menu, not on `Menu.Item` ?

Case when I put handler inside `Menu.Item` work fine. I need handler exactly in Menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `wrapper.find()` to target the `<Menu>` component specifically.

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'; // use mount instead

import { LeftMenu } from '../LeftMenu';
import { Menu } from 'antd'; // note we're importing the Menu component

const onMenuClickMock = jest.fn();

const defaultProps = {
  currentRoute: '',
  onMenuClick: onMenuClickMock,
};

const setup = props => {
  const setupProps = { ...defaultProps, ...props };
  return shallow(<LeftMenu {...setupProps} />);
};

describe('click on first menu item', () => {
  const wrapper = setup();
  const menu = wrapper.find(Menu); // Find component instance in wrapper
  menu.simulate('click', { key: 'home' }); // simulate click on menu
  expect(onMenuClickMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

By the way, *please* get in the habit of ending your statements with semicolons. It is not technically "required" by the JavaScript standard, but it is universally practiced by professional developers and makes the code easier to read and safer to write in case you make typos.

Comment: You could also use `const menu = wrapper.find('[data-test="component-left-menu"]')` if you want to take advantage of the data-test's in there.

Comment: @Maria that is true, `find()` can also work with any valid CSS selector. Generally I try and make my jest tests match, conceptually, what I'm trying to test. If he needs to test the behavior of clicking on an element that has that specific data attribute, then it would make sense. But here he is trying to test the behavior of clicking on a `<Menu>`, and ideally the test would reflect that. Targeting a data attribute is also rather specific to the internal implementation of the component. The test shouldn't care about that, it should treat things as a "black box" as much as possible. :)

Comment: I try both approach before asking here. It does not work.

Comment: @jered I'm implementing unit tests for particular component. You describe "black box" concept which is good for cypress or selenium. And I try to test with shallow because it's simple rendering without children for my particular component.

Comment: @IgorPopov how about `expect(onMenuClickMock.mock.calls.length).toBe(1)`

Comment: Ah I didn't notice that line. Normally I would test a mock function with `expect(onMenuClickMock).toHaveBeenCalled()`. Maybe try that, @IgorPopov .

Comment: @jered thanks a lot. expect(onMenuClickMock).toHaveBeenCalled() works fine

Comment: @Maria expect(onMenuClickMock.mock.calls.length).toBe(1) works fine too. My bad! I used "count" instead "length"! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @IgorPopov awesome! If your issue is solved, please mark an answer as "accepted" to clear this question from the queue. :)

Comment: @jered I can't accept because you example with mount does not work. It work only if I change mount to shallow. I don't know why